# Defining one function within another in R

Tags: r

```
findols <- function(x) {
  findol <- function(xrow) {
    mdn <- median(xrow)
    devs <- abs(xrow-mdn)
    return(which.max(devs))
  }
  return(apply(x,1,findol))
}
```

The function takes in a matrix and returns a vector where each element corresponds to the observation in each row that is furthest from the median.

**Question:** I don't understand how the function knows what xrow is equal to. In the exercise the function was called using findsols(x) where x is the matrix. How does the function know to interpret xrow as the row of the matrix?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is what `apply(x,1,findol)` is doing:

`apply` with 1 as second argument apply's a function (in your case `findol`)
to each row of its first argument (in your case `x`)

So `findols` returns `findol(x[i,])` for **i = 1 to Number of rows of x**.
Apply also handles the data-management for you and returns an object that contains the result of all rows.

For more information have a look at `?apply`

Answer (score 0):

xrow is the formal argument.  The actual argument is the rows of x.

Think about apply(x,1,sum) - this is the sum of the rows of x, right?  Same idea in your example.

You can prove this to yourself with a simple example:

```
> x <- cbind(rep(1,5), rep(2,5))
> x
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    1    2
[4,]    1    2
[5,]    1    2
> apply(x, 1, sum)
[1] 3 3 3 3 3
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in the `apply` function, you are actually doing:

```
return(apply(x, 1, function(whichrow) findol(xrow = whichrow)))
```

Look at what `?apply` does